# Hard fault in FreeRTOS in xPortPendSVHandler

Tags: c, arm, freertos, cortex-m

I have a hard fault occurring in my FreeRTOS application running on ATSAME54 (ARM Cortex-M4).

I am only using statically allocated memory. The hard fault occurs when I am sending CAN messages to it at a very high rate. I need to run it for a couple of seconds up to one minute.

The type of hard fault is a precise BusFault error (`CFSR.PRECISERR` and `CFSR.BFARVALID` bits set), with a `BFAR` of `5a5a5a5a`.

I decoded the stack frame using the code from https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html.

This gives:

```
r0  = 200030e8   <= part of a task stack
r1  = 200030a4
r2  = 5a5a5a5a   <= same as BFAR
r3  = 20003934
r12 = 2000317c   <= pxCurrentTCB
lr  = a5a5a5a5   <= ????? could this be the reason?
pc  = 00000955   <= in the middle of xPortPendSVHandler
psr = 00000960
```

Following the memory task stack `r0` points to, the FreeRTOS memory starts. I have put a memory barrier in between the two as one of my tests, but this stays untouched, so if there is corruption of the stack it is not by something writing from the FreeRTOS memory into my task stack.

The `5a5a5a5a` value happens to be the integrity check value that FreeRTOS adds to its structures. The `a5a5a5a5` is the normal fill value for stack memory.

What more can I try to find out what is causing this?

Comment: atollic studio will decode it for you :). IMO best IDE so far.

Comment: You should debug and stop at the hardfault handler, you should easily find the PC before the interrupt and the instruction that caused the invalid memory access. If you use an ide with debug capabilities, or gdb this should be straighforward as it should decode the stack for you automagically.

Comment: @P__J__ I agree, Shame it is not longer support for non ST processors.

Comment: @RealtimeRik it is a part of the STM. But unfortunatelly instead continue to work on atollic, they released th STMCubeIDE - which is not even close to the orinal atollic

Comment: @Damiano if it was so easy when debug RTOS apps ....

Comment: What's the difference? even if you have multiple tasks the sp points to the current task stack and the instruction that originated the hardfault (and It's preciseerr too)

Comment: @Damiano I had already tried what you suggested, decoding the stack frame to retrieve the program counter. The point is that the program counter points to halfway an instruction, not the start of an instruction. And yes, it is a precise error, but I do not know where the invalid memory address comes from.

Comment: @MartijndeMilliano it's normal that the istruction lowest bit is 1. It indicates that the instruction is a thumb one. That the only instruction set supported by Cortex-m. You should ignore the lowest bit.
Please update your question with disassembly of around that instruction, stack and register values from the same debugging session. I'll get a look.

Comment: @Damiano Thanks for your remark about the lowest bit. I understand that this is about the contents of the instruction, but I realised that the PC should always be an even value. I added an answer of how I resolved the issue by going bare metal. Thanks for your offer of taking a closer look. Unfortunately, I have had to hand back the hardware so I cannot provide more details. I guess we’ll never know.

Answer (score 2):

`xPortPendSVHandler` is `FreeRTOS`'s context switcher. If a bus fault happens in there you may have a corrupted process stack pointer as a result of a corrupted task control block in SRAM, besides the corrupted stack frame. You may want to use a static analyzer to check the code for common bugs like NULL-pointer de-references, array index out-of-bounds and such. In addition, the fact that it only happens when sending messages at a high rate makes it look like a racing related problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I could not find the issue. I resorted to removing the FreeRTOS altogether and replace it by some bare metal code. This worked flawlessly. This is, however, not a satisfying solution route, and is also not a general solution in case of issues with FreeRTOS.f

During my research, I found that ARM program code should be word-aligned or half-word aligned (16-bit or 32-bit wide instructions), so `0x955` is a strange value for a program counter. It is also remarkably close to the value of the PSR so this makes me wonder whether the stack decoding happened correctly and whether the PC at the time of the hard fault was not actually pointing elsewhere.

Comment: Note that 0x960 is a strange value for the PSR. Have you considered stack misalignment? The stack must be 8-byte aligned on exception entry & exit (see ARM DDI0419C B1.5.7). The compiler takes care of this for C code, but if there's any hand-coded assembler it must be fastidious about maintaining 8-byte stack alignment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and, in fact, it is related to a stack overflow.

In my case I was decoding a temperature sensor (DHT22) using rising / falling edges interruptions in a specific GPIO pin. I was storing the interval between edges in a buffer array and incrementing it in every interruption event.

The fact is that due to some electrical intermitency my buffer was growing insanely high and the stack boundaries were violated.
In my case I solved it with a single conditional limiting the size of the buffer,i.e., I set a 'growing limit' for it!

Answer (score 0):

had a similiar issue, in my case enlarging the task stack size from 128 words to anything larger solved the issiue for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).